# Youtube data api not sorting by viewCount

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get youtube channel videos sorted by viewCount, from high to low. But the result is not sorted by largest number of views.

Below is the API I am using:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={api-key}&channelId={channel-id}&part=snippet,id&order=viewCount&maxResults=20
```

Comment: Did you mange to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your API request seems to retrieves the results sorted by **`viewCount`** as expected.

I tried with YouTube Channel "[Mindless Self Indulgence](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw)".

The API request is as follows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet%2C+id&channelId=UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw&maxResults=20&order=viewCount&fields=items(id%2Csnippet(channelId%2CchannelTitle%2Cdescription%2CpublishedAt%2Ctitle))%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CtokenPagination&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

You can [try here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet%252C%20id&channelId=UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw&maxResults=20&order=viewCount&fields=items(id%252Csnippet(channelId%252CchannelTitle%252Cdescription%252CpublishedAt%252Ctitle))%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination&_h=1&) the previous request.

The results of the request are:

> N.B ignore the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags:

```html
<pre>
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "nextPageToken": "CBQQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 140,
  "resultsPerPage": 20
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "dM6elRs7F5k"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2007-01-04T00:06:56.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "**Mindless Self Indulgence \"Straight To Video\" music video**",
    "description": "\"Straight To Video\" from \"You'll Rebel To Anything\" (UCR/Metropolis) Director: Poz Lang DP: Daniel Fickle Producer: Jim Muscarella for Hi Tide Pictures ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "UR0UkTiKxmc"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2008-08-05T23:09:09.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence \"Never Wanted To Dance\" Music Video",
    "description": "Trouble with the volume? Report it at http:/ /tinyurl.com/6aeoe2 This is a YOUTUBE error, not on MSI's end...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "0GLoHifu6aM"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2011-01-13T01:41:10.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "The Left Rights - \"I'M ON CRACK\" Music Video",
    "description": "Video by Mike Diva http://www.youtube.com/mikediva Co-Director Pedro Flores http://www.youtube.com/peedeeflo \"Bad Choices Made Easy\" is out NOW: CD: ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2006-07-10T20:54:29.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence",
    "description": "The OFFICIAL YouTube source for all things Mindless Self Indulgence -- be sure to subscribe for news on the upcoming MSI music videos, and exclusives!",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "xfBQppaKcS8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2010-11-02T21:33:13.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "The Left Rights - Genesis 16:12",
    "description": "Music video for The Left Rights' \"Genesis 16:12\". Created by M dot Strange. http://www.youtube.com/user/mdotstrange The Left Rights are Jimmy Urine & Steve, ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "JGMFzvvsrpg"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2006-08-02T22:24:11.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence - \"Stupid MF\" (live) Worcester, MA",
    "description": "Mindless Self Indulgence performing \"Stupid MF\" live on the Cursing in Braille tour. Recorded at The Palladium on 7/20/2006 in Worcester, MA. Video Crew: ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "PNFjLzVKVdk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2013-10-15T01:20:26.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence \"It Gets Worse\" Lyric Video",
    "description": "Created by M dot Strange Album available here: http://bit.ly/ 146xOB9 Tour info here: http://on.fb.me/17c5OY9 \"It Gets Worse\" digital single available here: ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "s_Gyh1r-ut0"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2009-01-12T06:27:32.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence - Mark David Chapman Official Music Video",
    "description": "MSI's \"Mark David Chapman\" Video by Mike Diva http://www.youtube.com/mikediva Get the song and music video (in 3 formats including iPod, iPhone, and HQ) ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "CQUy82eN43g"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2010-11-09T20:04:20.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "The Left Rights \"FREE PORN\" Music Video",
    "description": "\"Bad Choices Made Easy\" is out NOW: CD: http://www.metropolis-mailorder.com/product.php?prodnum=MET+687 Deluxe MP3 Album: ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "AFEHvYNz490"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2008-04-21T02:46:58.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence - MSI's \"Animal\" by M dot Strange",
    "description": "From the limited edition deluxe version of MSI's new album, \"IF\" (out NOW worldwide). Order it now at http://www.theomegaorder.com/msi Modeled, rigged, ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "DjQzoIHyW2w"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2007-08-30T02:17:49.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence 'Golden I'/'Our Pain Your Gain' DVD",
    "description": "Mindless Self Indulgence perform \"Golden I\" from the upcoming MSI debut DVD, \"Our Pain, Your Gain\" in stores September 11th. Want to win MSI concert tickets, ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "BF9BgIOb2Ew"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2007-09-07T20:32:31.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence 'Clarissa'/'Our Pain Your Gain' DVD",
    "description": "http://www.reccenter.com & Mindless Self Indulgence bring you "Clarissa" from the upcoming MSI debut DVD, "Our Pain, Your Gain" in stores September 11th.",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "XtjTxDU2XFI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-11-03T18:50:13.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence - Personal Jesus (Official Video)",
    "description": "Directed by Yarvo. Buy \"Pink\": http://smarturl.it/getpink \"Pink\" Bundle: http://merchnow.com/catalogs/mindless-self-indulgence/bundles.",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "17kGWHLg3wU"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2013-08-02T18:55:56.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence - How I Learned To Stop Giving A Shit & Love Mindless Self Indulgence",
    "description": "Sign up for the website and add your tour history! http://mindlessselfindulgence.com/past-shows/ 1- \"Witness\" 0:00 | 3:16 2- \"Fuck Machine\" 3:17 | 6:40 3- \"It Gets ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "-kXrv10hr2I"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2006-08-01T23:31:27.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence Give Fan A Haircut Onstage!",
    "description": "Mindless Self Indulgence give a fan a haircut on the Cursing in Braille tour. Recorded at The Palladium on 7/20/2006 in Worcester, MA. Video Crew: ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "NNcM11Bx7VM"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2006-09-01T17:05:44.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence - \"Bring The Pain\" live in NJ",
    "description": "Mindless Self Indulgence performing \"Bring The Pain\" live on the Cursing in Braille tour. Recorded at the Starland Ballroom on 7/21/2006 in Sayreville, NJ.",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "k37WOBvc6vU"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2006-10-03T21:57:07.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence - \"Pay For It\" (live) Worcester, MA",
    "description": "Mindless Self Indulgence performing \"Pay For It\" live on the Cursing in Braille tour. Recorded at The Palladium on 7/20/2006 in Worcester, MA. Video Crew: ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "xIQtBPTTrwE"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-02-03T20:46:29.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence \"Fuck Machine\" AMV Cartoon",
    "description": "Animation by MoreFrames Animation Art by BiteyTheVillain Sign up for the website and add your tour history! http://mindlessselfindulgence.com/past-shows/",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "nL7-oPP-_ZA"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-12-06T15:22:48.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence \"It Gets Worse\" NEW DEMO!",
    "description": "HOW I LEARNED TO STOP GIVING A SHIT AND LOVE MINDLESS SELF INDULGENCE is out now: http://bit.ly/ 11mfkoY.",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "wRR-_O3kbX8"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2006-07-12T19:22:03.000Z",
    "channelId": "UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw",
    "title": "Mindless Self Indulgence - \"Brooklyn Hype (1+2)\" (live) NYC",
    "description": "Mindless Self Indulgence performing \"Brooklyn Hype (Parts 1+2)\" live at a secret show under the alias Bette Davis Eyes. Recorded at CBGB's on 2/24/2004 in ...",
    "channelTitle": "Mindless Self Indulgence"
   }
  }
 ]
}
</pre>
```

I did check that the results are correct by following these steps:

- Using the [videos.list API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), use the videoId `dM6elRs7F5k` returned in the first element of the previous results and its `viewCount` value is set to `9921351`. For the second item returned in the previous results *(that is, the videoID `UR0UkTiKxmc`)* I did the same request to the [videos.list API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and its `viewCount` value is set to `4798354`.

Here is the ["try-it"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22statistics%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22dM6elRs7F5k%22%7D#try-it) for the videoId = `dM6elRs7F5k`

Here is the ["try-it"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22statistics%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22UR0UkTiKxmc%22%7D#try-it) for the videoId = `UR0UkTiKxmc`

- [Thanks to this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79054/207498), you can retrieve the most vieewd videos from a given channel_id by modifying the URL.

  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChS8bULfMVx10SiyZyeTszw/videos?sort=video_view_count

By matching the results from the search.list API and the results shown in the website *(by entering the URL above)* - you can check that the results from the API are accurate.