# How to view youtube video without being counted?

Tags: html, youtube

I try to view yt video without being counted and still being able to control quality (resolution). All I found is to build `<iframe>` with embedded video that is autoplayed. That's not exactly what is usefull for me nor normal human being. I don't want to build a html page with `<iframe>` every time I want to see video. The best would be to add some option to address (like `&t=123`) or something like that.

As last resort bunch of options I can pass using input form like here (obviously it's analogy, duckduckgo is not video service):

```
<form action="https://duckduckgo.com/" name="q" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="40"> <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

I tried to find something useful but everyone is concerned about counting their view rather than not counting them therefore noone seems to ever do such feat.

PS. If title is incorrect/bad grammar please tell me that; I somehow "feel" like it doesn't sounds well.

Comment: I don't remember in which part of the YouTube Player API (iframe) documentation I read that a video in a iframe is not counted - you have to check if I'm right, though. My point with this is: you can change the URL of the youtube video to embed- like, search a vide on YouTube, click in "share" and copy the embed URL video. Sample: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID`

Comment: I will have to test it. How long it takes YT to update view count? I watched two "desolated" videos, one with and one without embedding but their count didn't change.

Comment: `How long it takes YT to update view count?` = no idea, honestly. Only YouTube has such information. I kind of remember reading that the viewcount is not exact due to some calculations... Check this [answer sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54426490/12511801) about the results of the `viewCount` from a given video.